# generics with implicit class conversion scala

Tags: scala

I have two case class `Customer` and `CustomerResponse` and implicit function for conversion from customer to response

```
case class Customer(name:String)
case class CustomerResponse(customerName:String)

object CustomerImplicits {
  implicit def customer2CustomerResponse(value : Customer) =
                                   new CustomerResponse(value.name)
}
```

Im trying to create a generic function where I can pass lot of classes and perform operation

```
def getEntityArray[T,U](idArray:Array[String]):Array[U] = {
    val records:Array[T] = getRecords[T](idArray)
    if(!records.isEmpty) {
      val ret = records.map( aRec => aRec:U)
      return ret
    }
    else 
      return Array.empty[U]
  }
arr = getEntityArray[Address,AddressResponse](array)
```

I'm getting an error T does not conform to expected type U. Is there any way to pass the implicit conversion `CustomerImplicits` to the `getEntityArray` function

Comment: What's `T` parameter supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3):

Consider changing from `Array` to `List` and pass implicit conversion `implicit ev: T => U` argument like so

```
def getEntityList[T, U](ts: List[T])(implicit ev: T => U): List[U]
```

For example,

```
def getEntityList[T, U](ts: List[T])(implicit ev: T => U): List[U] = {
  ts.map(ev)
}

import CustomerImplicits._
getEntityList[Customer, CustomerResponse](List(Customer("Picard"), Customer("Worf")))
```

outputs

```
res0: List[CustomerResponse] = List(CustomerResponse(Picard), CustomerResponse(Worf))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to achieve this:

```
import scala.reflect._
def getEntityArray[T, U: ClassTag](idArray: Array[String])(implicit t2u: T => U): Array[U] = {
  val records: Array[T] = getRecords[T](idArray)
  if(!records.isEmpty)
    records.map( r => r: U)
  else 
    Array.empty
}
import CustomerImplicits._
getEntityArray[Customer, CustomerResponse](Array.empty)
```

However, it doesn't seem to be a good approach for several reasons:

1. Generic types have no relation with the parameters, that's why you can't make use of type inference.
2. You are using `Array`, which is basically a Java type, that's why you need to pass the `ClassTag` context bound to `U` for it to work. You can try `List` instead.
3. Using implicit conversions this way makes the code less readable. Maybe you can just call it explicitly `records.map(t2u)`, and even make `t2u` a normal parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    implicit class Convert[T](req: List[T]) {

    import CustomerImplicits._

    def gerResp: List[CustomerResponse] = {
      req.flatMap {
        case customer: Customer => customer :: Nil
        case _ => List.empty[CustomerResponse]
      }
    }
  }

  val customer = List(Customer("A"), Customer("B"), Customer("C"))

  println(customer.gerResp)
```

in place of asInstanceOf you can do any operation you want which is converting T => U

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: im basically looking at way to pass the implicit function for the case class conversion.

Comment: You have already written implicit converter for customer to customerReap just import in inside your implicit class it will convert any type of Customer to CustomerResp